# Comparando campos de varias TextBox para checar se há duplicidade

Tags: c#

Estou desenvolvendo um programa básico em C# onde o usuário vai inserir valores através de um leitor de códigos de barra. O mesmo será salvo em uma planilha de Excel para um futuro relatório.

O meu problema é que existe situações em que o usuário bipa o mesmo código duas vezes em textbox diferentes.

Queria saber se, ao clicar no meu button `Salvar`, tivesse um evento para comparar todos os meus textbox e checar se há valores repetidos, impedindo de salvar as informações duplicadas.

Segue abaixo código do meu Button Adicionar:

```
private void BtnAdicionar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{                
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application Excel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook sheet = Excel.Workbooks.Open("C:\\Users\\Core i3\\Desktop\\EtiqMasterBoxTornozeleira.xlsx");
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet x = Excel.ActiveSheet as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet;

    Excel.Range userRanger = x.UsedRange;

    int countRecords = userRanger.Rows.Count;
    int add = countRecords + 1;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma maneira simples de fazer isso é você usar um Array

```
        Int64[] valores = new Int64[3];
        valores[0] = Convert.ToInt64(textBox1.Text);
        valores[1] = Convert.ToInt64(textBox2.Text);
        valores[2] = Convert.ToInt64(textBox3.Text);


        int quant_campos = valores.Length;
        var groups = valores.Distinct().ToList();

        if(quant_campos > groups.Count)
        {

            MessageBox.Show("Existe Campos Duplicados");
        }
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, funcionou aqui, agora só preciso implementar um método pra ele não deixar salvar mesmo com campos duplicados, que é oque ainda esta acontecendo, mas ele ja acusa que há campos duplicados. Obrigado

Answer (score 0):

Algumas coisas não ficaram muito claras, mas vou tentar ajudar.
Você comenta sobre iterar os textboxs, e por isso, vou concluir que você não precisa confirmar as informações que já foram gravadas anteriormente na sua planilha.

Pois bem:

Salve cada *código de barras* (string) em uma [coleção de strings da sua escolha](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7y3x785f(v=vs.110).aspx#BKMK_Choosingacollection); mas antes, confirme se dentro dessa lista ainda não contem este "código de barras" que será salvo através do método [Contains](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/bb352880(v=vs.110).aspx):

```cs
ICollection<string> codesCollection = new List<string>();

private void AddBarCode(string barcode)
{
    bool isDuplicatedCode = codesCollection.Contains(barcode);

    if(isDuplicatedCode)
        throw new ArgumentException("O código de barras já foi adicionado.").

    codesCollection.add(barcode);
}
```

Comment: O seu tambem funcionou amigo, obrigado pela ajuda.